# Count numbers where three first digits equal last three

Tags: java, permutation

How do I efficiently count the zero padded six digit numbers where the first three digits equal the last three?

My solution is like this. But this is not efficient solution. I have to find best way

```
public class TicketNumber { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
   int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, count = 0; 
   String str=""; 
   for (i1 = 0; i1 <= 9; i1++) { 
      for (i2 = 0; i2 <= 9; i2++) { 
         for (i3 = 0; i3 <= 9; i3++) { 
            for (i4 = 0; i4 <= 9; i4++) { 
               for (i5 = 0; i5 <= 9; i5++) { 
                  for (i6 = 0; i6 <= 9; i6++) { 
                     if ((i1+i2+i3) == (i4+i5+i6)) { 
                        count++; 
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

I should print all numbers between 000000-999999 which compatible with i1+i2+i3 = i4+i5+i6 condition

Comment: or wait, it's a bit ambiguous what you are trying to do here? what comes after `100000` for example?

Comment: try `IntStream.range(0, 999999).forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%06d%n", i));`

Comment: Is this homework btw?

Comment: People, this is not a duplicate at all.... :-/

Comment: @vidstige no,it is interview question

Comment: @PeterLawrey which is Intstream class?please explain a bit more if it is possible

Comment: You can calculate the range for i5 and the value i6 which will make it at least 10x faster.

Comment: Your solution doesn't match the question (it only prints one value, no the combinations). Can you update the question?

Comment: @PeterLawrey how?I should print only numbers which i1+i2+i3=i4+i5+i6

Comment: @vusala I suggest you say that in the question. See my answer.

Comment: This is confusing, your code will not count 000001 as indicated in your example...

Comment: so `0000001`, `000010` and `234567` are not solutions.

Comment: Ok rewrote the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count all the values where the first three digits equals the last three digits. (As you solution suggests)

You can calculate the range for i4, i5 and the value i6 which makes this much faster.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= 9; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= 9; i2++) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 <= 9; i3++) {
            int sum = i1 + i2 + i3;
            for (int i4 = Math.max(0, sum - 18); i4 <= Math.min(9, sum); i4++) {
                int min5 = Math.max(0, sum - i4 - 9);
                int max5 = Math.min(9, sum - i4);
                if (min5 <= max5) // one solution for i6 each
                    count += max5 - min5 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

prints the same answer as your solution;

```
55252
```

This is a further optimisation, it recognises that the order of the first three digits doesn't matter.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= 9; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= i1; i2++) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 <= i2; i3++) {
            int different = ((i1 != i2)?1:0) + ((i1 != i3)?1:0) + ((i2 != i3)?1:0);
            int combinations = different == 0 ? 1 : different == 2 ? 3 : 6;
            int sum = i1 + i2 + i3;
            for (int i4 = Math.max(0, sum - 18); i4 <= Math.min(9, sum); i4++) {
                int min5 = Math.max(0, sum - i4 - 9);
                int max5 = Math.min(9, sum - i4);
                if (min5 <= max5) // one solution each
                    count += combinations * (max5 - min5 + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

What this does is say 123 or 132 or 213 or 231 or 312 or 321 have the same number of solutions. 111 has a factor of 1, 112 has a factor of 3 and 123 has a factor of 6.

Comment: Thank you very much!But I didn't understand logic.Can u give a link to understand this kind of logic please?

Comment: @vusala try to work it out with a pencil and paper. There won't always be a "link" to help you.

Comment: @vusala instead of trying every possible value, you can calculate the range of possible values. e.g. if you have a sum of `9+9+9` there is no point starting `i4 == 0` as there is no way this will have any matches. similarly if i4+i5 > i1+i2+i3 there is no point looping over i6. In fact there is only one or zero possible i6 values so you don't need to loop those either.

Comment: @vusala I have optimised it further. This is almost 6x faster.